# lib gdx json read error in android

Tags: java, android, json, intellij-idea, libgdx

Please HELP!! 
I'm trying to create a game using libgdx library in InteliJ idea. right now I'm creating the main menu UI of my game using scene2d. when i run my project on desktop it has no error but when i try to to run it on an Android device follow error occurs, below is the logcat response and the code used in skin.json

```
 //code
    {
          com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: { default-font: { file:      cute.fnt } },
          com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
           default: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round, font: default-font },
          },
          com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Window$WindowStyle: {
            default:  {
             titleFont: default-font
             }
           }
        }
```

and this is logcat response

```
07-31 15:50:08.004  13046-13069/com.game.new.android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 5537
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: uiskin.json
        at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:97)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.<init>(Skin.java:74)
        at com.game.new.new.create(new.java:37)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:241)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1640)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1363)
 Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading 

file: uiskin.json
            at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:683)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:95)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.<init>(Skin.java:74)
            at com.game.new.new.create(new.java:37)
            at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:241)
                at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1640)
                at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1363)
         Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Serialization trace:
        down (com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle)
                at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readFields(Json.java:787)
                at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:902)
                at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$1.readValue(Skin.java:404)
                at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:834)
                at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.readNamedObjects(Skin.java:425)
                at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.read(Skin.java:414)
                at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.read(Skin.java:410)
                at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:873)
                at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$1.readValue(Skin.java:404)
                at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:681)
                ... 6 more
         Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: No Drawable, NinePatch, TextureRegion, Texture, or Sprite registered with name: default-round-down
                at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.getDrawable(Skin.java:283)
                at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.get(Skin.java:139)
                at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$1.readValue(Skin.java:403)
                at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readFields(Json.java:780)
                ... 15 more
```

Comment: Some code might come in handy

Comment: [Check](http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=5330)

Comment: i love you so much!!!! thank you bro. may all good karma in the world be in your favor. :)

Comment: You welcome, just an advise - before posting on Stackoverflow, you should always google :)

Comment: actually i googled a lot. but there are too many answers and all the solutions i tried are the wrong ones. so instead of trying another solutions i  tried asking the people with higher knowledge. thank you so much!!